# Avoiding for loop in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, for-loop, pyspark, databricks

In Databricks, using Python, I have a set of transformations to unpack json columns, which look like that:
[image]

The problem is that the of number "company_locations_address" columns varies in the different datasets that I am working with. Usually it varies between 10 and 20. The column names are like "company_locations_address[0]", "company_locations_address[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svTbe.png)", "company_locations_address[2]", etc.

To apply the set of transformations, I am using functions executed in a for loop like that:

```
for column in df_companies.columns:
if "company_locations_address" in column:
    print(column)
    df_companies_clean = df_companies.transform(locationsAddressInitialTransformations)
    df_companies_clean = df_companies_clean.transform(locationsAddressAdditionalTransformations)
    df_companies = df_companies.join(df_companies_clean, ["companyId"], how="inner").drop(column)
```

All transformations run really fast when executed for a specified column but when I am executing them in a for loop it takes long time because they run on the driver node. I know that using a for loop is not a good idea.
My question is how else can I apply the set of transformations to various number of columns?

These are the transformations within the function locationsAddressInitialTransformations:

```
 def locationsAddressInitialTransformations(df_companies):
return (df_companies
  # Take location_<n>_address column
  .select(
      "companyId", 
      column
  )
  # locations_<n>_address
  .select(
      "*", 
      json_tuple(
          column, 
          "address_components", 
          "formatted_address", 
          "geometry", 
          "place_id", 
          "types"
      ).alias(
          "address_components", 
          "formatted_address", 
          "geometry", 
          "place_id", 
          "types"
      )
  ).drop(column) 
  # geometry
  .select(
      "*", 
      json_tuple(
          "geometry", 
          "bounds", 
          "location", 
          "location_type", 
          "viewport"
      ).alias(
          "bounds", 
          "location", 
          "location_type", 
          "viewport"
      )
  ).drop("geometry")
  # location
  .select(
      "*", 
      json_tuple(
          "location", 
          "lat", 
          "lng"
      ).alias(
          "latitude", 
          "longitude")
  ).drop("location")
  # viewport
  .select(
      "*", 
      json_tuple(
          "viewport", 
          "northeast", 
          "southwest"
      ).alias(
          "viewport_northeast", 
          "viewport_southwest"
      )
  ).drop("viewport")
  .select(
      "*", 
      json_tuple(
          "viewport_northeast", 
          "lat", 
          "lng"
      ).alias(
          "viewport_northeast_latitude", 
          "viewport_northeast_longitude"
      )
  ).drop("viewport_northeast")
  .select(
      "*", 
      json_tuple(
          "viewport_southwest", 
          "lat", 
          "lng"
      ).alias(
          "viewport_southwest_latitude", 
          "viewport_southwest_longitude")
  ).drop("viewport_southwest")
  # bounds
  .select(
      "*", 
      json_tuple(
          "bounds", 
          "northeast", 
          "southwest"
      ).alias(
          "bounds_northeast", 
          "bounds_southwest"
      )
  ).drop("bounds")
  .select(
      "*", 
      json_tuple(
          "bounds_northeast", 
          "lat", 
          "lng"
      ).alias(
          "bounds_northeast_latitude", 
          "bounds_northeast_longitude"
      )
  ).drop("bounds_northeast")
  .select(
      "*", 
      json_tuple(
          "bounds_southwest", 
          "lat", 
          "lng"
      ).alias(
          "bounds_southwest_latitude", 
          "bounds_southwest_longitude"
      )
  ).drop("bounds_southwest")
  # types
  .selectExpr(
      "*", 
      f"from_json(types, 'array<string>') as types_array"
  ).drop("types")
)
```

This is an example of the data within the company_locations_address columns. It follows the same structure in all company_locations_address columns. It is of type string.

```
{"address_components":[{"long_name":"Canada","short_name":"CA","types":["country","political"]}],"formatted_address":"Canada","geometry":{"bounds":{"northeast":{"lat":83.6381,"lng":-50.9766},"southwest":{"lat":41.6765559,"lng":-141.00187}},"location":{"lat":56.130366,"lng":-106.346771},"location_type":"APPROXIMATE","viewport":{"northeast":{"lat":70,"lng":-50},"southwest":{"lat":42,"lng":-142}}},"place_id":"ChIJ2WrMN9MDDUsRpY9Doiq3aJk","types":["country","political"]}
```

My goal is to unpack/flatten all company_locations_address columns. Right now, I am unpacking each column in a separate DataFrame and joining it back to the original one, using the companyId as shown in the code section above.

Comment: Could you show what `locationsAddressInitialTransformations` does?

Comment: I have edited the post and have added the transformations within locationsAddressInitialTransformations function.

Comment: thanks.  The transformation is okay.  You are not doing row looping which creates a huge bottleneck.  **column** loop is okay in this scenario.  The actual slow part is `join`, due to the lazy evaluation of spark, this join within loop will create a long execution plans.   Looking at your transformations (+join), at a glance, I think you can achieve the same result with some combination of `from_json`, `explode`, `select` without `join`.  Could you add your sample data and expected output in plain text?

Comment: Thanks! I have added the information to my post. I am doing the join because the exact number of company_locations_address varies and I can't hard code transformations for specific columns. These transformations needs to work for a different number of columns. This is why I am unpacking each company_locations_address columns in a separate DataFrame and then joining it back to the main one. By doing this I can process all company_locations_address columns no matter how many they are.

Comment: please add the your expected output.